# Using Django.test.client to check template vars

Tags: django, client, testing

I've got a view that I'm trying to test with the `Client` object. Can I get to the variables I injected into the `render_to_response` of my view?

**Example View:**

```
def myView(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        # do the search
        return render_to_response('search.html',{'results':results},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('search.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Test:**

```
c = Client()

response = c.post('/school/search/', {'keyword':'beagles'})
# how do I get to the 'results'
```

### EDIT:

From the [Docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Response), I'm pretty certain I should be using:

```
response.context["results"]
```

**...but** `response.context` AND `response.template` both return `None`

Comment: It looks like this might be a Django bug? http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, found my own answer. When you run a test on it's own, that stuff doesn't get filled in, but if you run it with `manage.py test` it will get filled in. If you'd like to get a standalone test to work, add this to the top of your script:

```
from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
setup_test_environment()
```

Here's my whole test environment setup at the top of my script (for reference):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

### Start ENV Setup
import os, sys
sys.path.append('/Users/me/Documents/Web/django_projects/myproject')

from django.core.management import setup_environ

import settings
print "Setting environment to:", setup_environ(settings), "\n"

from django.test.utils import setup_test_environment
setup_test_environment()
### Finish ENV Setup

#-------------------

# Start the Fun! >>
from myproject.myapp.models import mymodel
```